# insert data in table

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

When I insert data I can read them in DATAGRIDVIEW but I can't find stored data in Table1 when read it from databse explorer, in addition I lose data of the DATAGRIDVIEW after that.

is it the right way to send data to database?

```
conn.ConnectionString =
   "Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = 'table1.sdf';" +
   "Password = '....'; File Mode = 'shared read'; " +
   "Max Database Size = 256; Max Buffer Size = 1024";

conn.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Tp_Inr_Dosage (date, Tp, Inr, LastDosage, NewDosage, pathology_level,  Pathology, idpatient) values( '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "', " + tpTextBox.Text.Replace(",", ".") + ", " + inrTextBox.Text.Replace(",", ".") + " ," + lastDosageTextBox.Text.Replace(",", ".") + ", " + newDosageTextBox.Text.Replace(",", ".") + " ," + pathologyComboBox.SelectedIndex + " , '" + pathologyComboBox.SelectedItem + "', '" + patient + "' )", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

It is like my data go to buffer only, it never reach database

Comment: Is there any exception / error-message? Is this perhaps the oh-so-common "I'm lookint at /MyProject/table1.sdf instead of /MyProject/bin/debug/table1.sdf? Unrelated: you should not concatenate SQL like that - you ***really*** need to use parameters

Comment: Hi, No error, code works well, I just can't find my Data in database. I lose all data in datgridview after opening table in database explorer

Comment: You really couldn't come up with a better title than that? Something that describes your problem a bit more specifically?

Comment: @boularouk and which file exactly are you looking at in database explorer? The database file in your project is ***not*** the database file that your app uses...

Comment: I open database explorer  of C#,  I click table to browse data.

Comment: Di you think I have to start my C# as an administrator?

Comment: @boularouk firstly, by "C#" here - do you mean "Visual Studio"? or...? But yes, from what you've said this is **exactly** opening the wrong file

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE, you might have a database file (sdf, mdf or similar) inside the project structure; maybe at `MyProject\table1.sdf`, or maybe at `MyProject\Data\table1.sdf`. When you use the IDE tools to look at the database, *this is the file you are looking at*.

However, when you build your project, the project files are written (copied) to the build location - so something like:

- `MyProject\bin\debug\table1.sdf`
- `MyProject\bin\debug\Data\table1.sdf`
- `MyProject\bin\release\table1.sdf`
- `MyProject\bin\release\Data\table1.sdf`

When you application runs, it is editing **the file in the build location**. Any changes you make to the data are only visible in **this copy** of the file. So: if you use any database viewing tools, you need to make *absolutely sure* you are looking at the file in the build location, and not in the original project location.

Comment: Ok, my table is located in the root MyProject\table1.sdf .but why I can't find my data in datagridview after that.

Comment: @boularouk impossible to comment without knowing how you are populating that datagridview, and *when* the data for that was taken. But: the *app* isn't looking at MyProject\table1.sdf - it is looking at MyProject\bin\debug\table1.sdf

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to do a insert is:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Tp_Inr_Dosage (date, Tp, Inr, LastDosage, NewDosage, pathology_level,  Pathology, idpatient) VALUES (@date, @Tp, @InRowChangingEventException, @LastDosage, @NewDosage, @pathology_level, @Pathology, @idpatient)";

SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SqlParameter("@date", DateTime.Now));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SqlParameter("@Tp", string.Empty));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SqlParameter("@InRowChangingEventException", string.Empty));
// etc.

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You don't need `CommandType.Text`. It is `Text` as a default.

Comment: To echo the comment on a very similar (now-deleted) answer: "This doesn't really answer his question, since using string concatenation isn't the source of his problem. Yes he should be using parameters, but that's a different issue." - the guidance to use parameters is a very good idea, but it is unlikely to be related to the actual issue

Comment: I think so, this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sqlCommands will tend to silently fail: encase the process in a generic try/catch block to see what it's failing to do correctly. Something like:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(ParameterisedSQlQueryText, conn);
    //Put your parameters in here
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex) {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
finally {conn.Close();}
```

the ex Message is usually a good indicator of what's gone wrong in these cases.

Comment: It it was silently failing, then by definition it isn't throwing; if it was throwing, the OP would have noticed, most likely

Comment: Generally, but I've had these issues (With OleDBCommands, though) where it doesn't throw, but if I try/catch it shows me what's gone wrong. No I don't know why.

Comment: Well, I suspect that the data simply isn't going where you think it is, as the comments on the question have suggested.

Comment: Yah, it is like it go to buffer or to virtual location a tableadapter?.

Comment: No, it is going to a copy of the sdf file, which is not the same one that you are viewing with the Database Explorer. Try hardcoding the ConnectionString to point to a fixed file somewhere, rather than a relative file in the project structure, then use whatever you have to look at *that* sdf